# Why does my Unity project work on my laptop but not on my desktop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity Project, I want to load a video, using this :

```
VideoClip clip = Resources.Load<VideoClip>("Videos/ChamberMusic/ChamberMusic_6K_QP0");
```

I then try to get the width by doing :

```
float videoWidth = clip.width;
```

At this point, I get :

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

By debugging, I found out that clip is Null, which I find odd because :

- The path is correct, the video exists and the folder "Videos" is at the root of "Resources", which is itself at the root of "Assets"
- The video doesn't seem to be corrupted because I can play it without any problem
- The .meta of the video says it's a VideoClip

Not finding any reason as to why it doesn't work, even after searching for like an hour online, I decided to try on my other computer. I cloned the project and surprisingly, it worked perfectly and I could load the video. I also tried on a friend's computer but this time, it didn't work on his.

So now I wonder how it works on one computer but not on others ? I'm thinking it may be due to Windows. The two computers on which it doesn't work are running on Windows 10 and the computer on which it works runs on Windows 11. In case this is the reason, here are the Windows specs.

```
Edition    Windows 10 Pro
Version    21H2
Installed on    ‎9/‎13/‎2021
OS build    19044.2251
Experience    Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0
```

```
Edition    Windows 11 Home
Version    22H2
Installed on    ‎10/‎2/‎2022
OS build    22621.819
Experience    Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22636.1000.0
```

But the idea that it's because of Windows seems a bit farfetched but I honestly have no clue and feeling lost. Is it possible it has something to do with some dependencies ?

Thanks for any help you could provide !

UPDATE : Turns out it was a problem with the videos I was trying to play, they must be too big or something because a really short video worked. It's probably an hardware issue so I'll leave this here in case anyone has an idea on what to do about this.

Comment: `Resources.Load<VideoClip>("Videos/ChamberMusic/ChamberMusic_6K_QP0);` is the missing closing quote at the end of the path a typo?

Comment: @Juris Yes it was a typo, I fixed it, thanks!

Comment: When you say not working on your desktop, is that under unity or compiled up?

Comment: @BugFinder Under Unity

Comment: Spitballing here but it might be because of the codec - Have you tried using a different video file? Or checking whether it's a well supported video file? Maybe try using ffmpeg to convert the file to a h.264 .mp4 file and see if that fairs better

Comment: @John I did tried that and it turns out some of the videos I was trying to play are the problems. Too big or something, a small video worked so it's probably some hardware issues.